# jquery mobile plugin creation

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a plugin for JQuery Mobile. Does anyone have a template or examples to help? Currently, I have the following defined in myplugin.js

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
        var defaults = { e: 0 },
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        var h= $.myPlugin.getHtml(options.e);
        alert("here 1");
        if ((h != null) && (h != undefined) && (h.length > 0)) {
            alert("here 2");
            this.html(h);
        }
    };

    $.myPlugin = {
        getHtml: function (e) {
            var s = "";
            return s;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I am trying to initialize an instance of this plugin like such:

```
$("#pluginInstance", "#myPage").myPlugin({ e: 0 });
```

Oddly, neither alert dialog appears. There aren't any errors in the console either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](https://gist.github.com/1416414) or [this](https://gist.github.com/1559887)?

If you look how JQM is designed, the syntax is pretty similar. I'm also sticking with it, when working on plugins I'm doing.